# CSS: Causing line breaks for inline elements without <br />

Tags: css

How can I have each of these a elements break on to new lines, but keeping them as display=inline and without **br** tags?

```
<div>
   <a href="element1">Element 1</a>
   <a href="element1">Element 2</a>
   <a href="element1">Element 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to make them inline elements but have line breaks after them? That's pretty much the definition of the difference between block elements and inline elements

Comment: No, the difference between block and inline elements is more subtle than that.

Comment: I guess he wants to put them on different lines, and he is allowed to change the CSS but not the HTML.

Comment: As Dietrich says, there is more to block elements than just breaking lines. Partly I'm just asking out of curiosity though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this by defining equal `width` for the parent `<div>` and the `<a>`. assuming you apply a class 'container' to the `<div>`

```
.container { width: 100px; }
a { width: 100px; display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 18):

This can be done, but will not work for all browsers. You need to use the `:after` pseudo-element with `white-space` and `content`. Like so

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div a:after {white-space: pre;content:'\A';}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <a href="element1">Element 1</a>
   <a href="element1">Element 2</a>
   <a href="element1">Element 3</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content

Comment: Five years later browser compatibility isn't a problem anymore but it's still not a universal solution as there are elements which don't have any ::before or ::after pseudo elements - e.g. `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

This can now be implemented reliably with css grid

```
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

div a {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For the block element not occupy the whole line, set it's width to something small and the `white-space:nowrap`

```
label
{
    width:10px;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.probablyShouldPutAClassName a {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -5):

Put them in an unordered list?

Not sure I really understand what you're after here...

Comment: If you don't understand don't answer it.